# Как склеить несколько текстовых файло не трогая при этом файлы которые мне нужны?

Tags: bash

Есть куча текстовых файлов с разными именами и разного размера. Надо взять и склеить их в один исключая при этом файлы которые имеют какое-то статическое название Как это сделать?

Я пытался написать скрипт для этого, но не могу придумать алгоритм

```
#!/bin/bash

SRCD='/media/sysadmin2/Data/Project/zvonar-api/zvonar/additionally/'
FILES=`find ${SRCD} -name "*.txt"`
# echo $FILES

if [ -z "$(ls -A ${SRCD})" ]; then # если пусто, то выходим
    exit 0
else
    for file in $FILES; do # пробегаемся по всем файлам в директории и сравниваем по условию. Исходя из условия выполняем тот скрипт который нужно в фоновом режиме
        filename=$(basename $file)
        result="${filename%.*}"
        echo $result

        if [ $result == 'IT_diallist' ]; then
            echo "звоним IT_diallist"
            rm -f ${SRCD}IT_diallist.txt
        else
            cat ${SRCD}$file > ${SRCD}diallist.txt
            rm -f ${SRCD}*.txt

        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: Вам нужно склеить все файлы кроме тех которые называются `IT_diallist.txt`?

Comment: Да, верно! Нужно склеить все кроме тех которые называются IT_diallist.txt

Comment: `$ find /где/то -type f -not -name плохое.имя -exec cat {} \; > новый.файл`